# Setting an object ACL using header from REST api is not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am writing files into Google storage from appengine  using REST api.

My code looks like this:

```
        url = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/' + bucketName + filePath

    LOG.debug('Attempting to write file: ' + url)

    '''
    compute expiry time one year in the future
    '''
    expiresDate = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=zconfig.CACHE_EXPDAY)
    formatStr = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'

    start_cloud = time.time()

    headers = {'Content-Type' : mime,
               'Content-Length' : len(imageBytes),
               'Cache-Control' : 'Expires=' + expiresDate.strftime(formatStr),
               'x-goog-api-version' : '2',
               'x-goog-acl' : 'public-read'}

    resp, content = http.request(url, 'PUT', body=imageBytes, headers=headers)
```

As per the google storage api docs, the REST api takes a 'x-goog-acl' header that can change the ACl on the object.

However, after this object is created, the ACL is still not set to public-read. I can see that both from gsutil, as well as from the GS browser.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: jterrace pointed out that I am not passing the headers into the request. I fixed that. But it still does not set the public-read ACL on the object.

Comment: Did you forget to pass the headers dictionary to the request function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not actually passing the headers dictionary to the request function:

```
resp, content = http.request(url, 'PUT', body=imageBytes)
```

should be:

```
resp, content = http.request(url, 'PUT', body=imageBytes, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that. However, even after doing that, it still does not set the public-read ACL on the object.

Comment: That should be working. If it's not, could you post the full HTTP request and response for the PUT call?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant. I can see the failure in my GAE logs. I cant run the app locally because it uses AppAssertion credentials. Seeing that you work in google, I can send you details offline?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. I run my scenario and the object shows up in google storage. However, when I go to the google cloud storage in browser, the "Share Publicly" option is disabled for the object. yet, I can see the object as an anonymous user if I use curl. Is the share publicly option different from it being visible to an anonymous user over HTTP?

Comment: Try the new cloud console: https://cloud.google.com/console

What does "gsutil getacl gs://bucket/object" return?

Comment: I get: GSResponseError: status=403, code=AccessDenied, reason=Forbidden, detail=bucket/object. This inspite of me being project-owner on the project.

Comment: Also the cloud console shows the same thing, that I do not have permission to view or change object ACLs

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know exactly why/how, but I think you are not logged in as the project owner when you visit the old and new console. The old console will not display the "share publicly" option (and will not allow you to toggle it) if you don't have permission to get/set object ACL. The new console is better in the sense that it actually tells you that.

Can you double check that the user you logged in as is the owner of the project?